# React Hooks onClick event: call child function before calling parent function

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-hooks

In my code below, how to call `executeBeforeToggle` function before executing parent's function `togglePage`?

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

const Page1 = (props) => {  

  //how to call this function before toggling?
  const executeBeforeToggle = () => {
    alert('HOORAY')
  }

  return (
      <div>
        <h1>I am Page 1</h1>
        <button onClick={() => props.togglePage()}>Toggle</button>
      </div>      
    )
};

const Page2 = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>I am Page 2</h1>
      <button onClick={() => props.togglePage()}>Toggle</button>
    </div>      
  )
}

const App = () => {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(false)

  const togglePage = () => {    
    setPage(!page)
  }


  if(page === false) return <Page1 togglePage={togglePage} />
  else return <Page2 togglePage={togglePage}  />
}



render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly, but actually that is simple:

```
const Page1 = (props) => {  

  const executeBeforeToggle = () => {
    alert('HOORAY')
  }

  const handleClick = () => { // click handler which exec both funcs
    executeBeforeToggle();
    props.togglePage();
  }

  return (
      <div>
        <h1>I am Page 1</h1>
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Toggle</button>
      </div>      
    )
};
```

So the main idea is that your click handler should be a function which executes both `executeBefore` and `togglePage` functions in the order you need. You may write that right inside the buttons `onClick`, or (as above) create separate function and pass it into the `onClick` what makes code a bit more readable.

Comment: How about add an async function `const executeBeforeToggle = async() => {
    alert('HOORAY')
  }` and use then `executeBeforeToggle().then(()=>{props.togglePage()})` just to make sure function executes in order what OP wants?

Comment: Thanks, this works. Actually, on my actual code, I am using typescript and just tried to create a similar scenario.

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna that will work, but actually doesn't make any sense since there is no asynchronous functionality :) Moreover it will return a promise, so all the es/ts linters may complain that there is unhandled promise passed into click handler.

Comment: Accepted the answer. Sorry, rookie mistake, in my actual code in typescript, I just need to change the type from
`saveDataOrReturn: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLDivElement>` to `saveDataOrReturn: () => void`.
This is not related to my post but your response help me pinpoint where I did wrong.
I thought there are other ways to fix my issue.